# IntelliJ / WebStorm Editor Colors not showing correctly

Tags: syntax-highlighting, intellij-idea, webstorm, coffeescript

I'm running WebStorm 10.0.2, and for an unknown reason someday my CoffeeScript code started showing only some highlighting. I have no idea of what's going on since the settings seems to be fine.

Changing Color Scheme yields no result as well - they're all kinda broken in the same manner. Removing and re-adding the CoffeeScript plugin had no effect as well. Any idea on how to fix that?

Here's a sample of how it is and how settings shows it should be:
[image: sample of real file vs. settings]